# Entity Framework With .Net Core is inserting duplicated records

Tags: entity-framework-core

i am using .net core 5 webApp (on IIS) with EF . when user is adding new record, from time to time duplicated records will inserted to the table every few seconds (like session is stuck... it want stop untill i restart the application pool). not happening every time, but indeed every few records.

my db is sql.

my code below:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProductId,Name,Category,Color,UnitPrice,AvailableQuantity")] Products products)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(products);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(products);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't an EF Core issue. If the *client* makes two identical POSTs, EF will insert two records. The DbContext is scoped to the request itself and gets disposed after the request completes

Comment: Does `ProductID` have a value? Is it a primary key? Trying to INSERT the same PK twice should result in an exception, not duplicate rows.

Comment: ProductID  is PK auto increment. each row gets different id.

Comment: Which frontend library do you use? As said, it's not EF.

Comment: i submit the object using .net core 5 post form (if that is what u r asking)

Comment: Add logging to your code to see what's actually going on. I suspect you'll see multiple POST requests. You can also configure HTTP logging either [in ASP.NET Core itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) or IIS. BTW .NET 5 reached End Of Life 7 months ago. The current Long Term Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024

Comment: In ASP.NET Core you can enable HTTP logging with `app.UseHttpLogging();`

Comment: *if that is what u r asking* -- It probably will be revealed if you show the code that calls the API endpoint.

Comment: the question is why 10-20 records can post normaly, and some can act in a post loop